# Find and print the sum of all integers in a text file

Tags: java, file, while-loop

I know there are similar question on SO but this is unique I think.

I have devised a simple program that reads a file and then adds up al the integers in the file and print the result, for example if the file had the numbers
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
then the program would print 55

However i have trouble when non integers are put into the file for example if it was 
1 2 3 string 4 5 6 test 7 8 9 10
then i get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
    at Week7.Task3.filereader(Task3.java:25)
    at Week7.Task3.main(Task3.java:14)
```

My code is as follows

```
package testing;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class summingInts
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws IOException
    {
        Scanner textfile = new Scanner(new File("intSum.txt"));

        filereader(textfile);
    }   


    static void filereader(Scanner textfile)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        while(i <= 9)
        {
            int nextInt = textfile.nextInt();          
            //System.out.println(nextInt);             
            sum = sum + nextInt;
            i++;    
            //System.out.println(sum);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

From what I can work out I think I should replace the while statement with a while (read.hasNextInt()) but from here I am stuck. I should probably say first I'm in java and secondly I plan to eventually have the program so that it adds up all the integers in the program and then adds up the number of none integer characters too and prints that too but I'll start with this :)

Comment: Think about what output you want. Do you still want to sum up all the integers? Then you have to read every line, not "while has next int". So when you read each line, figure out if its a String or Integer, and if it's an Integer add it to your total. Everything here can be Googled with a thousand examples in Java.

Comment: For what it's worth I have tried googling this shockingly, I have also tried to use the read.hasNextLine and then if that is true read.hasNextInt and sum them else add one to a count of int nonInteger that's not working either.

Answer (score 0):

Put a try/catch around your call to textFile.nextInt() and catch the InputMismatchExceptions.  That way you can count the non-numbers and keep the exception from breaking you out of your loop.